# Add objective C file to swift project

Tags: swift

I'm facing issue in adding ObjectC files to my swift project. I have added the .h and .m files, created the bridging objc header file with name `<#projectname#>-Bridging-Header.h`.  My .m file is also visible in the build face compile source. But when i try to access my objc class in swift methods. I get this compiler error ***Use of unresolved identifier 'xxxxx'***
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Hey Buddy Just Follow this url....[Swift And Objective-c][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to add the objc bridging header to the swift compiler in the build settings. This solved me the problem.

Comment: how do you add the bridging header?

Comment: @Turowicz The bridging header is a regular header that you specify as a "Objective-C Briding Header" in the Swift compiler settings. For more details, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html